# Send an email with a file and each time the file name is with the current time

Tags: ssis

I have a task for executions to send a file that has been downloaded from the database
and I will have to send the file by e-mail with the name of the time the file was sent.

what would be the order of execution of this task in integrated services
with the use of file system task and send email task in ssis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt, you should create your with file system task at first and save it where you wish. after that with using "Script Task" in control flow, you can send it easily. You just add these sources in "using namespaces" block:
"using System.Net.Mail;"

The Code you need to add in public main method should be like this:

```
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        string sSubject = [Your Subject Name String];
        string sBody = [Your Body String];
        string sEmailServer = [The Address of your Email Server];
        string sEmailPort = [The Email Port];
        string sEmailUser = [Your Email address];
        string sEmailPassword = [Your Email Password];
        string sEmailSendTo = [The Receiver Email];
        string sEmailSendCC = [The CC Sender Email];
        string sEmailSendFrom = [The Sender Email];
        string sEmailSendFromName = [The Sender Name];
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;(Normal, Low, High).

        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(sEmailSendFrom, sEmailSendFromName);
        message.From = fromAddress;

        string[] sEmailTo = Regex.Split(sEmailSendTo, ";");
        string[] sEmailCC = Regex.Split(sEmailSendCC, ";");
        int sEmailServerSMTP = int.Parse(sEmailPort);

        smtpClient.Host = sEmailServer;
        smtpClient.Port = sEmailServerSMTP;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;

        System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredentials =
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sEmailUser, sEmailPassword);
        smtpClient.Credentials = myCredentials;

        if (sEmailTo != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sEmailTo.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (sEmailTo[i] != null && sEmailTo[i] != "")
                {
                    message.To.Add(sEmailTo[i]);
                }
            }
        }            

       if (sEmailCC != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sEmailCC.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if (sEmailCC[i] != null && sEmailCC[i] != "")
                        {
                        message.To.Add(sEmailCC[i]);
                        }
                }
        }

        Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment([The path the file you saved]);
        message.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);

        message.Subject = sSubject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;
        message.Body = sBody;

        smtpClient.Send(message);
```